# if select selected how to remove div block?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-select

If select box selected one id item how to remove div from page. not hide ?

```
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option id="remove" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> if selected this  option ?
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<div id="remove">how to remove this div ?</div>
```

I don't know how to remove div block when option is selected?

Comment: What do you already have in terms of JavaScript related to this? Furthermore, why would you need to remove and not just hide the div?

Comment: i need make options. if i choose mercedes remove div block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:- Id's need to be unique. So instead of `id` use `value` itself to remove the div***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'mercedes'){
      $(this).next('div#remove').remove();
    }else{
      $(this).next('div#remove').remove();
      $(this).after('<div id="remove">how to remove this div ?</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<div id="remove">how to remove this div ?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily using `jquery`. You just need to listen for the dropdown change. And when the dropdown is changed and it's value is `mercedes` then remove the `<div>` with `id=remove`. The reason to add id in the `<select>` dropdown is to prevent the listner from conflicting with other `<select>` elements, if you use many `<select>` element in the HTML page in future. Or else, simply use

```
$('select').change(function(){
```

instead of

```
$('#cars').change(function(){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   //listen for the dropdown change
   $('#cars').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() === 'mercedes'){
        //remove the element from dom
        $('#remove').remove();
      }
   });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='cars'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> if selected this  option ?
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<div id="remove">how to remove this div ?</div>
```

Comment: it is possible to after remove back again ?

Comment: I did not understand that.